# Calculate the representation of field vectors

Tags: vector-spaces

Calculate the representation of field vectors  $$V(x,y)=\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}}\left(\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x}+\dfrac{\partial}{\partial y}\right)$$
In polar coordinates.

For this, is enough the change of variables $x=r\cos(\theta)$ and $y=r\sin(\theta)$ then $V(r,\theta)=r\nabla ??$,thanks!

Comment: This is an ***operator*** $r\nabla \cdot (\ldots)$ !!!

Comment: @NgChungTak, sorry but, what refer with calculate the representation of field vectors? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align*}
  \sqrt{x^2+y^2}
  \left(
    \mathbf{i} \, \frac{\partial}{\partial x}+
    \mathbf{j} \, \frac{\partial}{\partial y}
  \right) &=
  r\nabla \\
  &=r\left(
       \mathbf{e}_{r} \frac{\partial}{\partial r}+
       \frac{\mathbf{e}_{\theta}}{r} \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}
     \right) \\
  &=\mathbf{r} \frac{\partial}{\partial r}+
    \mathbf{e}_{\theta} \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} \\
  r\nabla \cdot \mathbf{A} &=
  r \frac{\partial A_{r}}{\partial r}+
  \frac{\partial A_{\theta}}{\partial \theta}
  \end{align*}